# Ubuntu 20.04 can't detect seagate 12T hard drive

Tags: boot, hard-drive

**[Temporary Solution]** We encountered strange problems with the hard drive while installing Ubuntu. I hope someone here can provide us with some suggestions.
We try to install ubuntu on a workstation with one 1T Samsung SSD on the M.2 port and one 12T Seagate hard drive on the SATA port. Our motherboard is **ASUS Pro WS WRX80E-SAGE SE WIFI**. However, Ubuntu in 18.04, 20.04.4 and 20.04.1 could not detect the 12T Seagate hard drive during installation, while Windows 10 could easily detect it. Even after installing Ubuntu on SSD, we can't see the hard drive through `sudo fdisk -l`.

Meanwhile, the output of `sudo lsblk` is demonstrated as follows:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1         7:1    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1328
loop2         7:2    0  65.2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
loop3         7:3    0  43.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/14978
loop4         7:4    0 248.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
loop5         7:5    0  54.2M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/558
loop6         7:6    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1405
loop7         7:7    0  44.7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/15534
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  93.6G  0 part
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   509M  0 part
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0 837.4G  0 part /
```

We have tried to switch the SATA port connected with the hard drive, but it still did not work.

I would appreciate it if anyone here could help us solve this problem!

Update:

1. We have tried the latest Ubuntu 22.04. Unfortunately, it also did not work.
2. The screenshot of GParted:

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `sudo lsblk`? Have you confirmed that the SATA controller is properly recognised and running in Ubuntu? 

Comment: Thanks for your help! The 12T hard drive is not shown in ```sudo lsblk```. Meanwhile, I use ```lspci``` command, and there is ```2b:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)``` included in the output. I am not sure whether I do the correct check. Could you please provide me with some suggestions on this matter? @matigo

Comment: Kindly reconfirm that ubuntu has already installed in the say SSD. If so can you see it in the GUI?

Comment: Hi @ManOnTheMoon, Yes, we have installed the ubuntu 20.04.1 in the SSD, but we still cannot see the 12T hard drive in the GUI.

Comment: +1: Please create a 'formal answer' and after a couple of days you should [be able to] 'accept' it by clicking on the tick icon. That way other users have a better chance to find your temporary solution. - By the way, it would be interesting to learn if the newest available Ubuntu, for example a live USB drive with the developing version [Kinetic Kudu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) has a driver, that works with a 12 TB drive. So if you have time to test it, please let us know :-)

Comment: @sudodus Hi, thanks for your suggestions. I have created and accepted a formal answer to describe our temporary solution. Meanwhile, we add the model of our motherboard in case someone else with the same model meets a similar problem. As described in the main question, we have tried several Ubuntu system versions, and none of them worked. Currently, we are exhausted because of the long time consumed in finding our 'temporary solution', and we may try your advice in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who meets the same problem as us.

**There is a temporary solution to this issue.**

We think it is a problem with the Linux SATA driver on the motherboard. Our motherboard is **ASUS Pro WS WRX80E-SAGE SE WIFI**.

Unfortunately, we did not find a permanent solution to this issue. Our temporary solution is to connect the 12T hard drive to the M.2 port through **an M.2/SATA converter**.

Furthermore, remember to change the corresponding M.2 port from 'PCI-E' to **'SATA'** mode in BIOS.

Detailed Step: Enter BIOS setting -> Advanced -> Onboard Devices Configuration -> U.2_* mode -> 'PCI-E' to 'SATA' -> Save and exist.

* represents the id number of the M.2 port used to connect the hard drive.

Comment: It probably is worth it to file a bugreport against the sata driver.

Comment: @Rinzwind Hi, we are happy to provide a bug report if it could benefit the Linux community. But we are a newcomer to this community, so could you offer us some suggestions about where to submit such a bug report?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling SR-IOV in the BIOS